# SQL exercise improve a query AdventureWorks

Tags: sql

im looking to improve my SQL skills, and i find this exercise without a solution.
The exercises go like this:
The production department needs to analyze the products that have the word Bikes as part of their subcategory names and a list price between 3K and 4K. (K means 1000) The information required is as follows:

Product: ID, Name, Color, reorderpoint, standardcost, safetystocklevel, listprice, daystomanufacture Model Name and Description
Subcategory Name Category Name
Consider that the StandardCost field should show with only two decimals – Data type: decimal(10,2)
[Click here for AdventureWorks Schema](https://akela.mendelu.cz/%7Ejprich/vyuka/db2/AdventureWorks2008_db_diagram.pdf)

so far my solution go like this:

```
SELECT p.ProductID, p.Name, p.Color, p.reorderpoint, p.StandardCost, p.SafetyStockLevel, p.listprice, p.DaysToManufacture, pm.Name, pd.Description, psc.Name, pc.Name
FROM              Product p LEFT JOIN ProductModel pm
                                         ON p.ProductModelID = pm.ProductModelID
                            LEFT JOIN ProductModelProductDescriptionCulture pmpdc
                                         ON p.ProductModelID = pmpdc.ProductModelID
                            LEFT JOIN ProductDescription pd
                                         ON pd.ProductDescriptionID = pmpdc. ProductDescriptionID
                            LEFT JOIN ProductSubcategory psc
                                         ON psc.ProductSubCategory = p.ProductSubCategory
                            LEFT JOIN ProductCategory pc
                                         ON pc.ProductCategoryID = psc.ProductCategoryID

WHERE    UPPER(psc.Name) LIKE “BIKE%” AND p.listprice  BETWEEN  3000 AND 4000 ;
```

I do not know why but i think i may have some issue here, or maybe everything is wrong

Comment: Adventureworks is a sample database for sqlserver  , have you imported to mysql or is there a version for mysql or is the question wrongly tagged?

Answer (score 0):

psc.ProductSubCategory = p.ProductSubCategory should be psc.ProductSubCategoryid = p.ProductSubCategoryid

and

“BIKE%” should be 'BIKE%'

and in adventureworks2012 which is the last version I have to hand there are 12 bikes returned using your query as fixed, but not in the price range you are looking for. I suggest you fix and run with the where clause excluding price while you investigate further

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Adventure Works database the names in the Product Subcategory table as Mountain Bikes and Road Bikes, so your where clause should be '%bike%'

Comment: thanks for the answer! so it should be : UPPER(psc.Name) LIKE “%BIKE%” ?

Comment: By default SQL Sever is case insensitive.